# Regex not picking up 8/8 for test case

Tags: c++, regex, vector

> Write a C++ program that identifies and counts words and special names in a textual file. A word is defined as a sequence of one or more non-whitespace characters separated by whitespace. In this assignment, a word is defined as a special name if it starts by an underscore `_`, or `@` character, and followed by at least one letter, that may be followed by zero or more letters, digits, or underscores `_` characters. Such that, no two adjacent underscore characters are allowed. The program should count all occurrences of words and all occurrences of special names. For example, `@value`, `_val9`, `_num_234_ten`, and `@num_45` are valid special names, but `$9val`, and `@_num`, `@8num`, `_num__234` are not.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <regex>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

bool isValidSpecialName(const string& word) {
    static regex reg(R"((^@|^_)[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9_]*$)");
    return regex_match(word, reg) && word.find("__") == string::npos;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    if (argc < 2) {
        cout << "NO SPECIFIED INPUT FILE NAME." << endl;
        return 0;
    }

    ifstream infile(argv[1]);
    if (!infile.is_open()) {
        cout << "CANNOT OPEN THE FILE " << argv[1] << endl;
        return 0;
    }

    string line;
    int wordCount = 0, specialNameCount = 0;

    while (getline(infile, line)) {
        istringstream iss(line);
        string word;
        while (iss >> word) {
            wordCount++;
            if (isValidSpecialName(word)) {
                specialNameCount++;
            }
        }
    }

    if (wordCount == 0) {
        cout << "File is empty." << endl;
        return 0;
    }

    if (argc == 3) {
        string flag(argv[2]);
        if (flag == "-all") {
            cout << "Total number of words: " << wordCount << endl;
            cout << "Total number of special names: " << specialNameCount << endl;
        } else if (flag == "-sp") {
            cout << "Total number of special names: " << specialNameCount << endl;
        } else {
            cout << "UNRECOGNIZED FLAG" << endl;
        }
    } else {
        cout << "Total number of words: " << wordCount << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

infile1:

```
    # Simple _array_constructs.
    @fred = ("How", "are", "you", "today?");
    print "@fred contains ( @_fred ).\n";

    $mike = $fred[1];
    print " @mike _fred [3]\n";

    # The array name in a scalar context gives the size.
    @fred@size = @fred;
    print ' @fred has ', " @fred_size elements.\n";

    # The $#name gives the max subscript (size less one).
    print "Max sub is $#fred\n";
```

infile2:

```
  # Various operations on scalar (string) variables.
  _fred = Fred__here;
  @bar_ney = @56 + ;
  $sum = _10 + _barney ;
  print 'The variable $fred' . " contains $fred. \n";
  print "Sum is $sum. \n";
```

No matter how many different approaches I've taken, I can not get 8/8 special names to output from infile1, 60 words, 8 special names. In infile2 I get all 35 words, and 3 special names.

Stumped, I can not use boost library, I have to solve this with the regex library. I don't know how to approach it.

Comment: Your regexp doesn't prohibit adjacent underscores.

Comment: Why don't you have the program print the special names that it finds? Then you'll be able to see which ones it's not counting, and fix the bug that misses them.

Comment: Stack Overflow usage note: It's in your best interests to narrow the  question down to exactly one failure and hard-code in an input set that exposes this one error. Saying you can't get 8/8 doesn't really tell potential answerers (or future askers, and that's what makes a question useful) much about the problem you're actually facing.

Comment: 5 may be the correct result, what makes you think there are 8?

Comment: @Barmar bool isValidSpecialName(const string& word) {
    static regex reg(R"((^@|^_)(?!__)[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9_]*$)");
    return regex_match(word, reg) && word.find("__") == string::npos;
}
But I still found 5/8 on the test case

Comment: To add, your program should be a simple `main` function, no command-line arguments, no switch statements, no file I/O, etc.  It should consist of a simple `main` function, with hard-coded data that duplicates the problem, with a call to the `regex_match` function.  Nothing more than that.

Comment: minrepro @PaulMcKenzie: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/MKaqbbjv5

Comment: 1.@fred on line2 
2.@ fred on line3  ("@fred contains)
3.@mike on line6
4._fred on line6 (_ also counts, if it starts with an underscore it is also counted, if followed by a letter
5.@fred@size starting on line 9  (one word)
6.@ fred also on line 9 after the =
7. @fred on line 10 inside the ' '
8.@fred_size   (one word)

The only invalid word is @_fred , it can not start with both. This is what I counted by eye

Comment: There is no special on line 3 of the input.  The so-called word is `"@fred` which doesn't start with `@` or `_`.  Just the first of three mistakes in your manual count.

Comment: `@fred@size` is not a match, you can't have `@` in the middle. `@fred;` after `=` is not a match because it ends with `;`.

Comment: starting with an underscore is also valid special name for the test case, as long as its followed by one letter

Comment: @DavidCzerepak -- `"@fred` does not start with a `@` or `_`.  It starts with a `"`.

Comment: @DavidCzerepak:  I give you permission to **edit** your post with input data samples, instead of placing the data into comments.  Editing your post will make the data more readable than placing into your comment.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, the code is correct and the unit test has a bug.

With a little bit of instrumentation, I can confirm that the correct result is 5 not 8.

The `while` loop is replaced by

```
int lineno = 0;

while (getline(infile, line)) {
    ++lineno;
    istringstream iss(line);
    string word;
    while ((iss >> word)) {
        int column = iss.tellg();
        if (column > line.size()) column = line.size();
        column -= word.size();
        if (column < 0) column = 0;
        
        wordCount++;
        if (isValidSpecialName(word)) {
            std::cout << "Found special '" << word << "' on line " << lineno << "\n";
            std::cout << line << "\n" << std::string(column, ' ') << std::string(word.size(), '^') << "\n";
            specialNameCount++;
        }
        else if ((word.find('_') != string::npos) || (word.find('@') != string::npos)) {
            std::cout << "You can't fool me, '" << word << "' on line " << lineno << " is not special\n";
            std::cout << line << "\n" << std::string(column, ' ') << std::string(word.size(), '!') << "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

and the output is

```
You can't fool me, '_array_constructs.' on line 1 is not special
  # Simple _array_constructs.
           !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
Found special '@fred' on line 2
  @fred = ("How", "are", "you", "today?");
  ^^^^^
You can't fool me, '"@fred' on line 3 is not special
  print "@fred contains ( @_fred ).\n";
        !!!!!!
You can't fool me, '@_fred' on line 3 is not special
  print "@fred contains ( @_fred ).\n";
                          !!!!!!
Found special '@mike' on line 6
  print " @mike _fred [3]\n";
          ^^^^^
Found special '_fred' on line 6
  print " @mike _fred [3]\n";
                ^^^^^
You can't fool me, '@fred@size' on line 9 is not special
  @fred@size = @fred;
  !!!!!!!!!!
You can't fool me, '@fred;' on line 9 is not special
  @fred@size = @fred;
               !!!!!!
Found special '@fred' on line 10
  print ' @fred has ', " @fred_size elements.\n";
          ^^^^^
Found special '@fred_size' on line 10
  print ' @fred has ', " @fred_size elements.\n";
                         ^^^^^^^^^^
Total number of words: 62
Total number of special names: 5
```

For anyone who wants to enhance it further, minrepro: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/9Tns4d9aj

Comment: on line 9 you have: @fred@size = @fred;  those are three valid special names that qualify under the rule @ or _ followed by a letter, I think this is what I'm missing

Comment: They aren't valid according to the rules in the question.  In my new version that prints the tricky words, pay very careful attention to how far the `!!!!!` spans.

Comment: I agree with you I believe that the output I have to match and the description of the rules is misleading. I think the problems description is incorrect or worded inaccurately. The output in the system I'm using to solve this is telling me there are 8 special names. I will send an email and get to the bottom of this. I also thought about matching all _ and @ followed by a letter and weeding out the ones I know are not correct. I'll continue to try different ways to solve this

Comment: Can you feed the old system some much simpler testcases, like `@fred@size` (by itself, that's the whole file) or `_array_constructs.` or `"@fred` or `@fred;` ?  We cannot really help you with your specification bugs here.